# Creating object in for loop

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Is there a difference in creating the object inside and outside for loop..I am not sure but i am experiencing an error with the oCategoryDefinition  being declared outside of forloop :

> Invalid cast from 'System.Int32' to 'xxx.CategoryDefinition'
>        at System.Convert.DefaultToType(IConvertible value, Type targetType, IFormatProvider provider)
>        at System.Int32.System.IConvertible.ToType(Type type, IFormatProvider provider) at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider) at 
>       Service.AddFeatureValues(VINDescription vinDescription, VehicleDescription vehicleDescription)

>

```
  for (int i = 0; i < listLength; i++)
    {
        CategoryDefinition oCategoryDefinition = (CategoryDefinition)Convert.ChangeType
         (vehicleDescription.genericEquipment[i].Item, typeof(CategoryDefinition));
        vinDescription.StandardFeature.Add(oCategoryDefinition.category.Value);
    }
```

AND

```
CategoryDefinition oCategoryDefinition = new CategoryDefinition();

for (int i = 0; i < listLength; i++)
{
   oCategoryDefinition = (CategoryDefinition)Convert.ChangeType
       (vehicleDescription.genericEquipment[i].Item, typeof(CategoryDefinition));
   vinDescription.StandardFeature.Add(oCategoryDefinition.category.Value);
}
```

**EDIT**

To add one angle to the issue : Below is the method which is firing the **above error**:

```
 private void AddFeatureValues(VINDescription vinDescription, VehicleDescription vehicleDescription)
    {
        GenericEquipment[] genericEquipList = null;

        //To add standard features to the vehicle details list.
        CategoryDefinition oCategoryDefinition =  new CategoryDefinition();

        try
        {
            genericEquipList = vehicleDescription.genericEquipment;

            if (genericEquipList != null)
            {
                //Stores the number of items in generic list.
                int listLength = genericEquipList.Length;

                for (int i = 0; i < listLength; i++)
                {
                    //Casting the object type to CategoryDefinition type.
                    oCategoryDefinition = (CategoryDefinition)Convert.ChangeType(vehicleDescription.genericEquipment[i].Item,
                                            typeof(CategoryDefinition));
                    vinDescription.StandardFeature.Add(oCategoryDefinition.category.Value ?? "N/A");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {  
        }
    }
```

Comment: The only difference when creating it inside and outside the loop, is the object/variable scope

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how the error message is related to your code ?

Comment: I can't make sense to the rest of the question/issue.  Fix it please

Comment: @Johan there's more of a difference than just scope -- heap allocation.  But regardless, that wouldn't be the cause of the exception.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear...i have edited the question..Apologies again..

Comment: Can you show more details of your objects and where, specifically, you're getting the exception?

Comment: @DavidHoerster fair enough, but based on the way the question was asked, going into all that would confuse the OP even more...

Comment: @RatanSharma your problem is the conversion, not the object being creating inside/outside the loop.

Comment: @Johan..i understand that..but the error start coming just after this change only..so was worried

Comment: @RatanSharma is the error only happening in one of the cases? or both?

Comment: When oCategoryDefinition  is created outside of forloop..i am getting the error.

Comment: @RatanSharma the only major difference I can see, is that the one instantiates it (outside the loop) and the other one doesn't.

ie, the new CategoryDefinition();

Comment: Also, where exactly does the exception occur.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try the following, as the only major difference is the new keyword.

```
CategoryDefinition oCategoryDefinition;

for (int i = 0; i < listLength; i++)
{
   oCategoryDefinition = (CategoryDefinition)Convert.ChangeType
       (vehicleDescription.genericEquipment[i].Item, typeof(CategoryDefinition));
   vinDescription.StandardFeature.Add(oCategoryDefinition.category.Value);
}
```

However, the cast exception isn't really helping my claim.

Comment: Please have a look at the complete method in the question

Comment: Where does the exception happen? at what line does it break?

Comment: oCategoryDefinition = (CategoryDefinition)Convert.ChangeType(vehicleDescription.genericEquipment[i].Item, 
                                            typeof(CategoryDefinition));

Comment: and if you change it back to inside?

Comment: haha dammit, what else have you changed?

perhaps something in the 'CategoryDefinition' class?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17294/discussion-between-ratan-sharma-and-johan)

Answer (score 0):

In the second case you can still reference the object that lasted after the last iteration because of extended variable scope (ex. method), hence it's safer to use the first version.

However (depending on how framework implements creating the reference) it may cause slight performance impact, which is significant when number of iteration goes big.